# Convert doc file to html using Apache Poi

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am working on an android application in which i need to convert MS office files to HTML using Apache Poi.
Till now i am able to convert .xlsx to htm using the following project Source-

http://display-msoffice-docs-android-with-apache-poi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/TestOfficeAndroid/

i can see that there is a `WordToHtmlConverter` class in `org.apache.poi.hwpf.converter` package which can convert .doc file in its main method as its `main()` method takes the input file path and output file path as argument.
But when i invoke the main method of WordToHtmlConverter, it gives classnotfound exception exception for `java.rmi.unexpectedexception`. 
There is no java.rmi.unexpectedexception class for android.
How can i overcome this problem.
Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j)?  I don't know if it's the answer for you, because I've only just started working with it.  (I came across your question as I was looking on Stackoverflow to see if anyone had been using it to create HTML5, which I think should be fairly easy to do)