# How to Convert PDF to HTML-page in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, apache-poi, docx4j

I need to convert  PDF to HTML page in android. The reverse has been discussed on StackOverFlow a lot.

Thanks

Comment: Dont have much idea, but you can search something epub creator library. epub is a file format world wide used for ebook. it consists html pages.

Comment: Why Negative Voted ???

Comment: I think this will attract downvotes because it is sparse on detail, and it appears that you've not tried anything. For example, would a web service be OK here? Converting PDF to HTML is a tricky problem to solve well, since PDF is a coordinate-based object format, and characters in a sentence can be placed individually. On that basis, doing it outside of the device is almost certainly best.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer this question on stackoverflow which is already discussed
[Convert doc file to html using Apache Poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542498/convert-doc-file-to-html-using-apache-poi)
or
http://www.technophileshub.com/906/how-to-embed-pdf-document-in-html-page

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the PDFBox library:

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks but PDFBox library doesn't have support for Android .